# Why does this simple main method never return when run by leiningen?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

This piece of code returns immediately:

```
user=> (dorun (pmap + [1 2] [3 4]))
nil
```

However, when I run the same piece of code in main method using lein:

```
(ns practice.core)

(defn -main [& args]
  (dorun (pmap + [1 2] [3 4])))
```

why does it never return?

Interestingly, if I replace `pmap` by `map`, it returns normally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `shutdown-agents` at the end of your `-main` method.

```
(defn -main [& args]
  (dorun (pmap + [1 2] [3 4]))
  (shutdown-agents))
```

This is mentioned on http://clojure.org/agents:

> Note that use of Agents starts a pool of non-daemon background threads
>   that will prevent shutdown of the JVM. Use shutdown-agents to
>   terminate these threads and allow shutdown.

`pmap` uses futures which run on the agent thread pool.